# How to fix .zsh_history opening up every time I start the terminal

Tags: zsh, macos, oh-my-zsh

I tried to delete my zsh history following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771958/delete-specific-line-from-zsh-history) by @WebEpic. The issue is that now, every time I open my terminal, the .zsh_history opens via Vim. I need to quit it using `:qa` then it would go back to my original profile. I think the issue lies on the fact that I did something wrong on the step `navigate to your .zsh_profile with your arrow keys and press enter.`

This is a picture of how it looks now every time my terminal starts (the contents get updated with whatever command I use, this screenshot is just an instance):

[image]

and this is a picture of how it should look like (or after I press `:qa!`)
[image]

If I try to quit my terminal without pressing `:qa` it prompts "Do you want to terminate running processes in this window?".
I tried restarting my laptop but it does not work. Do you have any solutions?

---

If I open a new terminal at the same time, I get the error:

'E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/.zsh_history.swp".....'

[image]

I tried deleting this, with ‘rm ~/.zsh_history.swp‘ but the problem persists…
*I am using a MacBook Air M1 with macOS Monterey 12.2 installed*

Comment: I believe you have something starting the last command in the history in your `~/.zshrc`. Look for any stray `!` in there. The history file should not be opened automatically whatsoever under any circumstance.

Comment: @BrainStone how exactly do I access that? I used `vim ~/.zshrc` but the file is empty. I also tried deleting `.zsh_history.swp` but it still does not resolve the issue

Comment: I do not see `.zshrc` when I run `ls-a`